# How can I upload a PIL image object to Imgur API on python3?

Tags: imgur

I am getting the following error when I try to upload an image to imgur api.

```
b'{"data":{"error":"Invalid URL (<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1600x6495 at 0x10E726050>)","request":"\\/3\\/upload","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":400}'
```

My code is given below. Client ID is redacted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
from PIL import Image
import requests
import json
import base64

url = "http://www.tallheights.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/background_purple.jpg"
r = requests.get(url)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
imagestring = str(image)

url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload'
body = {'type':'file','image': imagestring , 'name' : 'abc.jpeg'}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID <redacted>'}

req = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
print (req.content)
```

My code is in Python3 and I am not using the [official client library](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython) provided by Imgur for two reasons.

1. The library provides me with only two options - a) Upload by specifying a URL and b) Upload from a local file. In my case, the image I want to upload is neither. It is an image processed by PIL, existing as a PIL object in memory. I do not want to use file system for this particular implementation.
2. A simple POST request to the API would do the job for me and I want to avoid the dependency to the library and keep the package as light as possible.

Comment: Which part of your code fails? Are you using the official API or not?

Comment: The error printed above is the JSON response from the IMGUR API. So it is not my code which is failing, rather the API.

Comment: Well anyway I have decided to use S3 instead

Answer (score 1):

This Works:

```
# imports
import requests
import io
from PIL import Image

# Get Image from request
img_response = requests.get(
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? q=tbn%3AANd9GcTVYP3ZsF72FSKPzxJghYkjz_-a1op7YxBK45O0Y4nTjAQ7PZKD"
)

# Some Pillow Resizing
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_response.content))
img_width, img_height = img.size
crop = min(img.size)
square_img = img.crop(
    (
        (img_width - crop) // 2,
        (img_height - crop) // 2,
        (img_width + crop) // 2,
        (img_height + crop) // 2,
    )
)  # Square Image is of type Pil Image

imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
square_img.save(imgByteArr, format="PNG")
imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()

url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image"


payload = {"image": imgByteArr}
headers = {"Authorization": "Client-ID xxxxxxxxx"}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text.encode("utf8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the API documentation, it seems like the /upload part of your url was changed to /image.

https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139

(see the "sample request" on the right side)

But it seems like this is all deprecated in general and the information on the very same page contradicts itself.

Comment: I noticed that and had tried with that path as well. Both resulted in the same error